# How to configure apache for Tor hidden service

Tags: onion-services, configuration, help, web-hosting, information-leaks

Which configuration file do I change in Apache to run it through Tor? I know you use:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
Server_name 127.0.0.1:8080;
```

I think, but I don't have much experience with web hosting, I know how to use Linux, but a little new to this area and I also heard that Apache can leak out info, any one have any documentation I may read or give some help on preventing that?

Comment: I have found the answer to this question in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default. If anybody else have similar question, she may refer to the above mentioned site for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Apache doesn't run through Tor. It is a service that listens on the ip address(es) and port(s) you specify in its config file. If you want to configure Apache to host only hidden services, then you limit your listening IP address to 127.0.0.1:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

After that, in the VirtualHost block, you put the onion address in the `ServerName`. For example:

```
ServerName ctygdx55hgoleuht.onion
```

and you assign to `DocumentRoot` the public html folder of your onion site.

Don't forget to configure your hidden service(s) in your `torrc` file, and specify `127.0.0.1`, not the server real IP, in `HiddenServicePort` there. For example:

```
HiddenServiceDir /path/to/hidden/service/private/key/dir
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Read [this page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) for more information about this topic.

Another important step is to minimize/stop your Apache leakage of webserver info that makes it identifiable. Edit */etc/apache2/conf.d/security* by adding/modifying two parameters like the following:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: And do not make a mistake with 127.0.0.1!! Use 127.0.0.2 or something, but NOT 127.0.0.1!! It increases your security greatly.

Comment: Is it necessary to change the ServerName to the onion address?

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin How so? It's only for port 80.

Comment: yes, but you can elaborate any other port(s) - just add a corresponding lines 'HiddenServicePort` and `Listen` to their configs. SSL works fine as well